# How to programmatically find out if a Webpage has a Video, Facebook Pixel, Google Analytics code or not?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script that goes through a bunch of websites and find out if those websites have a video on their landing page or not. If those websites have Google Analytics & Facebook Pixel or not.

I have grabbed the page's HTML and I am trying to parse it to get what I am trying to get but not sure if there's any better solution.

Comment: Are you fetching a page on a server (HTML code) and then processing it or are you running a script on a page?

Comment: I assume this is nodejs. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have grabbed the HTML using Cherrio. But I was wondering if there's any library to analyze the HTML content and figure out if the Webpage has Video, Facebook Pixel code, Google Analytics code and so on.

Comment: Any idea Pawel or David?

Comment: I don’t know if brainstorming is allowed on this forum but may be if you could grab all the resources and check their extensions, that could be a way to know if it has a video or not. 
For google and Facebook not really sure but may be check for `src` tags and do a match for domain names?